# How to connect to database in another directory?

Tags: php, sqlite

I use SQLite with PHP. With all PHP files in same folder it works. But I want files in different folders:

testCreate.php (1st folder):

```
<?php
class mySqlite extends SQLite3{
    function __construct(){
        $this->open('test.db');
    }
}
$db = new mySqlite();
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name`  TEXT NOT NULL);"
    );
?>
```

testAPI.php (1st folder):

```
<?php
require_once('testCreate.php');

function insert($name){
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->exec("INSERT INTO `test`(`name`) VALUES ('$name')");
    if($stmt){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function select(){
    global $db;
    if($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,name FROM test ORDER BY `id` DESC '))
    {
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $names=array();
        while($arr=$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
        {
         $names[]=$arr;
        }
        return $names;
    }
}
?>
```

insert.php (2nd folder):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['new_menu']) && !empty($_POST['new_menu'])){
    require_once('../incDB/testAPI.php');
    $qry = insert($_POST['new_menu']);
    if($qry) echo 'ok';
    else echo 'no';
}
?>
<form method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="new_menu">
    <button type="submit">ADD</button>
</form>
```

select.php (3rd folder):

```
<?php
require_once('../incDB/testAPI.php');
$rows = select();
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #000">id</td>
        <td style="border: solid 1px #000">name</td>
    </thead>
    <?php
       foreach($rows as $row){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: dashed 1px #000"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td style="border: dashed 1px #000"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

When I run insert.php or select.php I found the database in 2nd folder. I want insert and select data to/from database in 1st folder. I changed testAPI.php :

```
<?php
//require_once('testCreate.php');
class mySqlite extends SQLite3{
    function __construct(){
        $this->open('test.db');
    }
}
$db = new mySqlite('../incDB/test.db');
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
`id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`name`  TEXT NOT NULL);"
);

function insert($name){
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->exec("INSERT INTO `test`(`name`) VALUES ('$name')");
    if($stmt){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function select(){
    global $db;
    if($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id,name FROM test ORDER BY `id` DESC '))
    {
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $names=array();
        while($arr=$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
        {
         $names[]=$arr;
        }
        return $names;
    }
}
?>
```

Still same problem.

Comment: Use an absolute pathname for the `test.db`.

Comment: the testAPI.php , test.db and testCreate.php file in same folder. how can i use absolute pathname? in this situation the script is make test.db in same folder of insert.php file and in same folder of select.php file

Comment: The question says they're *not* in the same folder.

Comment: select.php and insert.php  not in same folder but the API in same folder of test.db

Comment: The problem is that relative pathnames are interpreted relative to the original script, not the API script. If the API can be used from different folders, you can't use a relative pathname in the API. You need to use the full pathname of the DB.

Comment: i update my code same mistake is still

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake

open function in testCreate.php need full path

the answer is

```
<?php
class mySqlite extends SQLite3{
    function __construct(){
        $this->open('../incDB/test.db'); /// in this line mistake
    }
}
$db = new mySqlite();
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `name`  TEXT NOT NULL);"
    );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create db_connection.php and use **DIR** to specify absolute path

```
<?php
class mySqlite extends SQLite3 {
    function __construct() {
        $this->open(__DIR__ . 'test.db');
    }
}

$db = new mySqlite();
```

And now all you need is to include connection.php and use $db. Even if you use two or greater folders deep it will work fine